# git pull without updating remote

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

Suppose I have already run `git fetch`, and now I want to run `git pull`, to bring my local `myBranch` up-to-date with my `origin\myBranch`.

BUT!! in the mean time, after running the `fetch`, my internet connection has dropped :( Now, when I run `git pull` it fails, because it can't see `remote`. But I'd like to still do the local portion of the pull.

Is there a way to tell `git pull` to run without doing the initial `git fetch`?

NOTE:
I could `git reset --hard` to update `myBranch`. But `git pull` doesn't always just do that.

I guess another way to phrase the question is "What second command satisfies: `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git ???`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it depends on your configuration.

In a default configuration, if you're on `my_branch` which has its upstream as `origin/my_branch`, then `git pull` can be considered as

```
get fetch
get merge origin/my_branch
```

Configuration (or command line arguments) can change what will be merged.  Configuration can also change the 2nd step from a merge into a rebase.  So when you say

> "What second command satisfies: git pull = git fetch + git ???"?

there's no one answer to what `???` is, but *by default* it would be merge.

Answer (score 5):

`git pull` is actually `git fetch` + `git merge`:

Comment: oh, is that all? Huh. Cool.

Comment: As the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) explains: *"In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`."*

Comment: The easiest way to bring your local working copy up to date is merging your local copy of the remote repo (which `git fetch` updated): `git merge origin/myBranch`.